# How to circumvent a "blockadblock" script with a benign adblock friendly substitute?

Tags: javascript, events, notifications, user-defined-functions, spoofing

A website I interact with employs the following adblock detection script (beautified for readability):

```
! function(t) {
    var e = function(e) {
        this._options = {
            checkOnLoad: !1,
            resetOnEnd: !1,
            loopCheckTime: 50,
            loopMaxNumber: 5,
            baitClass: "pub_300x250 pub_300x250m pub_728x90 text-ad textAd text_ad text_ads text-ads text-ad-links",
            baitStyle: "width: 1px !important; height: 1px !important; position: absolute !important; left: -10000px !important; top: -1000px !important;",
            debug: !1
        }, this._var = {
            version: "3.2.1",
            bait: null,
            checking: !1,
            loop: null,
            loopNumber: 0,
            event: {
                detected: [],
                notDetected: []
            }
        }, void 0 !== e && this.setOption(e);
        var o = this,
            i = function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    o._options.checkOnLoad === !0 && (o._options.debug === !0 && o._log("onload->eventCallback", "A check loading is launched"), null === o._var.bait && o._creatBait(), setTimeout(function() {
                        o.check()
                    }, 1))
                }, 1)
            };
        void 0 !== t.addEventListener ? t.addEventListener("load", i, !1) : t.attachEvent("onload", i)
    };
    e.prototype._options = null, e.prototype._var = null, e.prototype._bait = null, e.prototype._log = function(t, e) {
        console.log("[BlockAdBlock][" + t + "] " + e)
    }, e.prototype.setOption = function(t, e) {
        if (void 0 !== e) {
            var o = t;
            t = {}, t[o] = e
        }
        for (var i in t) this._options[i] = t[i], this._options.debug === !0 && this._log("setOption", 'The option "' + i + '" he was assigned to "' + t[i] + '"');
        return this
    }, e.prototype._creatBait = function() {
        var e = document.createElement("div");
        e.setAttribute("class", this._options.baitClass), e.setAttribute("style", this._options.baitStyle), this._var.bait = t.document.body.appendChild(e), this._var.bait.offsetParent, this._var.bait.offsetHeight, this._var.bait.offsetLeft, this._var.bait.offsetTop, this._var.bait.offsetWidth, this._var.bait.clientHeight, this._var.bait.clientWidth, this._options.debug === !0 && this._log("_creatBait", "Bait has been created")
    }, e.prototype._destroyBait = function() {
        t.document.body.removeChild(this._var.bait), this._var.bait = null, this._options.debug === !0 && this._log("_destroyBait", "Bait has been removed")
    }, e.prototype.check = function(t) {
        if (void 0 === t && (t = !0), this._options.debug === !0 && this._log("check", "An audit was requested " + (t === !0 ? "with a" : "without") + " loop"), this._var.checking === !0) return this._options.debug === !0 && this._log("check", "A check was canceled because there is already an ongoing"), !1;
        this._var.checking = !0, null === this._var.bait && this._creatBait();
        var e = this;
        return this._var.loopNumber = 0, t === !0 && (this._var.loop = setInterval(function() {
            e._checkBait(t)
        }, this._options.loopCheckTime)), setTimeout(function() {
            e._checkBait(t)
        }, 1), this._options.debug === !0 && this._log("check", "A check is in progress ..."), !0
    }, e.prototype._checkBait = function(e) {
        var o = !1;
        if (null === this._var.bait && this._creatBait(), (null !== t.document.body.getAttribute("abp") || null === this._var.bait.offsetParent || 0 == this._var.bait.offsetHeight || 0 == this._var.bait.offsetLeft || 0 == this._var.bait.offsetTop || 0 == this._var.bait.offsetWidth || 0 == this._var.bait.clientHeight || 0 == this._var.bait.clientWidth) && (o = !0), void 0 !== t.getComputedStyle) {
            var i = t.getComputedStyle(this._var.bait, null);
            !i || "none" != i.getPropertyValue("display") && "hidden" != i.getPropertyValue("visibility") || (o = !0)
        }
        this._options.debug === !0 && this._log("_checkBait", "A check (" + (this._var.loopNumber + 1) + "/" + this._options.loopMaxNumber + " ~" + (1 + this._var.loopNumber * this._options.loopCheckTime) + "ms) was conducted and detection is " + (o === !0 ? "positive" : "negative")), e === !0 && (this._var.loopNumber++, this._var.loopNumber >= this._options.loopMaxNumber && this._stopLoop()), o === !0 ? (this._stopLoop(), this._destroyBait(), this.emitEvent(!0), e === !0 && (this._var.checking = !1)) : (null === this._var.loop || e === !1) && (this._destroyBait(), this.emitEvent(!1), e === !0 && (this._var.checking = !1))
    }, e.prototype._stopLoop = function(t) {
        clearInterval(this._var.loop), this._var.loop = null, this._var.loopNumber = 0, this._options.debug === !0 && this._log("_stopLoop", "A loop has been stopped")
    }, e.prototype.emitEvent = function(t) {
        this._options.debug === !0 && this._log("emitEvent", "An event with a " + (t === !0 ? "positive" : "negative") + " detection was called");
        var e = this._var.event[t === !0 ? "detected" : "notDetected"];
        for (var o in e) this._options.debug === !0 && this._log("emitEvent", "Call function " + (parseInt(o) + 1) + "/" + e.length), e.hasOwnProperty(o) && e[o]();
        return this._options.resetOnEnd === !0 && this.clearEvent(), this
    }, e.prototype.clearEvent = function() {
        this._var.event.detected = [], this._var.event.notDetected = [], this._options.debug === !0 && this._log("clearEvent", "The event list has been cleared")
    }, e.prototype.on = function(t, e) {
        return this._var.event[t === !0 ? "detected" : "notDetected"].push(e), this._options.debug === !0 && this._log("on", 'A type of event "' + (t === !0 ? "detected" : "notDetected") + '" was added'), this
    }, e.prototype.onDetected = function(t) {
        return this.on(!0, t)
    }, e.prototype.onNotDetected = function(t) {
        return this.on(!1, t)
    }, t.BlockAdBlock = e, void 0 === t.blockAdBlock && (t.blockAdBlock = new e({
        checkOnLoad: !0,
        resetOnEnd: !0
    }))
}(window);
```

The site design is such that this script cannot be blocked without halting the functionality of the site. I haven't consented to any EULA with this site and I believe I'm well within my rights to tamper with my client side code. I simply wish to circumvent this script with a benign adblock friendly substitute.

Essentially, I'd like to inject a user-defined script that will simulate the adblock notification event and give the server the impression that I have clicked through the following popup notification:

[image]

The approach I'd like try for this problem was suggested by @jake-holzinger. He remarked the script might be subverted by forcing the `e` class prototype to trigger the opposite adblock detection code, i.e. by overwritting `e.prototype.onDetected` with `e.prototype.onNotDetected`; although, I assume the same effect can be achieved by flipping the Boolean? As he explains it, this subverted code should be executed prior to the `load` event, but only after the above default code is run (I could be misinterpreting this part).

As a novice with JavaScript, I find these instructions a bit terse and opaque. In particular, I'm not entirely sure what the control flow is supposed to look like here. It seems like the default blockadblock script should be run (not blocked or replaced), but for some reason this needs to take place before the subverted code? Is the "subverted code" in this case a perfect replica of the blockadblock script, with the only difference being the inverted event names; or Boolean? What does it mean for the subverted code to be run before the `load` event? Isn't this already the case? Or do I need restructure the code to achieve this effect?

Comment: Would be interested to know why this question was down voted.

Comment: try: create a browser extension that creates an immutable variable named `BlockAdBlock`  and one named `blockAdBlock` and load the extension at readystate 'loading'. Likely won't work. If you're interested, you can investigate how closures work. This code is in a closure and immune to your corruption.

Comment: If you trace the code, `t` is `window` and `e` is the "class" that does the work. Near the bottom of the snippet you see `t.BlockAddBlock = e`, here they are attaching the "class" to the `window` object. You can likely modify the "class" prototype to always trigger `onNotDetected` by overwriting `onDetected` with `onNotDetected`. This code would need to be run before the "load" event is fired, but after the above snippet of code is executed: `window.BlockAddBlock.prototype.onDetected = window.BlockAddBlock.prototype.onNotDetected`

Comment: Enlightening remarks, thank you both. I'll try to better reformulate the challenge after a bit more research.